# I can't redirect to home page after successful login using Keycloak "HomeURL" client parameter

Tags: keycloak, single-sign-on

My application logs in successfully to Keycloak using the following code. It works because I get my token

```
async function loginToKeycloak(username, password, clientId, realmName) {
    const keycloakUrl = 'https://<ip of my virtual machine where keycloak is running>:8443/realms/';
    const tokenEndpoint = `${keycloakUrl}${realmName}/protocol/openid-connect/token`;

    const data = {
        grant_type: 'password',
        client_id: clientId,
        username,
        password,
    };

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(tokenEndpoint, new URLSearchParams(data), {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            httpsAgent: new (require('https').Agent)({ rejectUnauthorized: false }),
        });
        return response.data.access_token;
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't redirect to my home page using the "Home URL" parameter of my client. In my server I have a home page which works because I can access it with the browser at the address "https://localhost:3000/home".

```
server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`listening on port ${3000}`);
});

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/home.html`);
});
```

Therefore I set the "Home URL" parameter of my client to "https://localhost:3000/home" but the redirection doesn't take place automatically after logging in. I left all other client parameters as default because I don't know well their meaning.